# Font awesome icons not appearing in Safari

Tags: css, safari, font-awesome

Font awesome icons are not showing in Safari browser(Ver 5.1.7). But it is showing perfectly in chrome, firefox, IE, Opera. Is there any special CSS tactics or any other techniques for showing up font icons in safari?

Comment: Safari 5.1.7 oO That was in 2012...

Comment: Ok fine..then is there any tactic for appearing font icons in such old  versions of safari browser?

Comment: Nobody should use such an old browser by today. If they do, they should not reach the internet for security reasons. This *browser* has not received **any** security update in 6 years. The best you can do if ever you have customers that do use this thing even Apple has rejected, is to tell them to either switch to a real macOS with an up to date Safari, either to use any other up to date browser available on windows.

Comment: In addition, i am currently working on windows. The latest available version of Safari for windows is 5.1.7.

Comment: Thank you @ Kaiido

Comment: Did you just installed Safari to test your Website in it? If so, it is not really helpful to use such an old version, since nobody of the "real" safari users will have this old version installed. And if you REALLY have users, that use that version, they maybe should not expect an up to date web experience in that browser.

Comment: Yes..i just installed for testing my project in safari. Thank you for sharing information..Cheers!